# CSS: Button which scales and shifts with resizing image

Tags: css

I have an image which shows a button. I would like to place an HTML button with the same size on top of that button. It should always exactly overlap that button in the image, no matter the scale or position of the image. The image is constrained by both relative width and height.

I tried

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img style="object-fit: contain; max-width: 100%; max-height: 80vh;" src="myimage.png" width="1461" height="1066"/>
    <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 10%; left: 50%; z-index: 1; width: 10%; transform: translate(-50%, 50%);">Test</button>
</div>
```

But because the image is constrained by the screen width, when the screen gets narrow, the button moves downwards. I.e. the button does not stay in place relative to the image, as desired.

And because the image is constrained by height, the button gets wider relative to the image when the screen gets wide.

(Also, if the screen gets wide, the button moves sideways, but I got rid of this problem by putting the enclosing div in a flex container.)

I am looking for an HTML and CSS only solution (no JavaScript).

Comment: I would use only flex box.  justify-content / self and align-items / self would go a long way.  Then you could use padding and margin values with percentages or viewport ratios to keep everything fluid and in place.

Answer (score 1):

> But because the image is constrained by the screen width, when the
> screen gets narrow, the button moves downwards. I.e. the button does
> not stay in place relative to the image, as desired. And because the image
> is constrained by height, the button gets wider relative to the image
> when the screen gets wide.

The percentage width you assigned to your button is what causes it to grow or shrink in width relative to the screen size - the `width: 10%;`. Unsetting that property will address your issue there.

As far as what you're hoping to achieve overall, I'm a bit little unclear on whether you want relative *sizing* or *positioning* or both for your button, but it sounds like you want to minimally be able to fix the button position relative to the image as it resizes. You probably want to avoid relative sizing with the button given the issues mentioned above. Just use padding and font to style the button and avoid setting the width explicitly to ensure your button accompanies your text and doesn't shrink or stretch at different screen sizes.

Right now your button is moved out of the normal flow and is only being positioned relative to your `position: relative;` wrapper. It doesn't know about the position and sizing of your image.

You could set the wrapper styles to reflect the behavior you generally want in your image and use this as a relative container for *both* your image and button. Using `position: absolute;` on the image and some percent vertical padding on the wrapper, you can mimic the resize behavior of your image - ex. if your image scales while maintaining a 3:2 aspect ratio the wrapper can have `padding-bottom: 66.6%;`.

Then, you can tweak your layout - ex. `top` and `left` etc - and sizing of both your image and button depending on how you want them to behave together relative to their shared container. Typically you want some element taking up 100% height of the relative wrapper so you aren't left with an odd gap in spacing for the surrounding elements that are in flow - ex. whatever comes after your image. This solution does depend on adjusting the relative wrapper to match your image aspect ratio, but if that's not an issue this is a common approach that may give you greater control.

Maybe the code below is closer to what you're hoping to accomplish? Here is is a fiddle link as well:

https://jsfiddle.net/abgregs/buysm3fq/1/

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 66.66%;">
  <img style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: auto;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x300" width="450" height="300"/>
  <button style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); z-index: 1; padding: 10px 20px;">Test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As the title says, I want relative sizing and positioning. So, that the HTML button always exactly fits on top of the button in the image. I clarified the question text accordingly.

Comment: I'm not going to do a full mock of your problem by creating an _image that shows a button on it_, as you're asking for quite a lot, but my solution has an image that scales by width and height with an HTML button positioned on the image such that you can achieve what you want. If the dimensions text showing in my placeholder image in my solution (the _450x300_ text on the image) was the button area of your image, here is your HTML button covering up your button: https://jsfiddle.net/abgregs/chuk7qm9/5/ Isn't this what you're describing? The HTML button always covers the same part of the image.

Comment: This seems to work mostly. However, "max-height: 80vh" is not respected.

Comment: Handling the logic for both those scenarios with a CSS-only solution  might be difficult. But at least this should help you reason around the issue. Your button needs some relative container to be positioned against, but I’m not sure how you’d get that container to behave exactly like your image. I’m not saying there isn’t a solution out there, but it may be worth revisiting the use case. Does your image need to have a button area? You're just covering it up anyway, right? Is the max-height rule strictly necessary? Is using a background image an option? Just trying to simplify.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive help, I appreciate it.
Currently, I do not see how I could simplify my use case (which I did not fully describe here).
I was essentially hoping that there was a solution to "wrap" a container around its content. But I see that it looks unreasonable that the parent and the child containers could both adjust to each other's size.
I guess I will have to use a JS solution, which at least should be quite simple to come up with, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Would a `height: 100%` on the img-tag solve the Problem?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80vh;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="myimage.jpg" width="1461" height="1066" />
  <button>Test</button>
</div>
```